# Deadlock when using std::async with future as member

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I transferred our app from Objective-C and Cocoa to C++.
In Objective-C I was frequently using Grand Central Dispatch and the very handy dispatch_async functions.

When moving to C++11, I found std::async as the closest equivalent.
I'm using Scott Meyers variant of it which makes sure it's really called asynchronously:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
inline auto NLA_async(F&& f, Ts&&... params)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async,
                      std::forward<F>(f),
                      std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
}
```

I learned that the function won't actually be called asynchronously if the returned future is not assigned as the future d'tor will wait for the async block to be finished.

```
void foo()
{
    NLA_async([]{ // run long task async });
    // future returned from NLA_async not captured 
    // -> std::future d'tor waits for block to be finished
}
```

So I thought I'd just assign the future to a class member so that it at least dispatches asynchronously in most cases (not ideal, but I thought a quick and dirty workaround). This worked well so far.

However I'm running into a deadlock situation which I don't yet understand.
It looks like it's possible that the block is executed twice at the same time which in my case causes a deadlock.

You can have a look here:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc4fcbaff370f1b9

Can anyone explain why this is executed twice at the same time?

Edit:
In my particular case the problem is that at the end of the async block the code locks a mutex, does some work and then unlocks the mutex. At this point, we're running into a deadlock. It looks like the running async block is deleted before it is finished as the mutex stays locked although it shouldn't (there are no return statements or anything that would explain why it wouldn't unlock the mutex).

Comment: Are you asking why, when you run 1,000 asynchronous background tasks, some of them execute concurrently? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The main function calls foo() on object. foo() dispatches an async worker thread using std::async, storing the future in the member variable _dispatchAsyncFuture. The next time the function is called, it should wait for _dispatchAsyncFuture to be destroyed and then dispatch it on a new (or the same) background thread (while assigning the new future to _dispatchAsyncFuture). Hence, there should never be more than one background task running at the same time, correct?

Comment: No! Put a `cout`before and after the `_count--` statement and see for yourself. The variable holding the future is overwritten. Could you post the code with the mutex?

Comment: Ok, so that shows that there are two blocks at the same time (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0615bee869a963aa). But why? Can you elaborate why the block doesn't finish before dispatching a new one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a minimum the compiler may create the new future in `NLA_async`, return it, and then block only when assigning it to the member variable (I'm not sure it even has to do that). If you want mutual exclusion, this is a super cheesy and indirect way of doing it - on top of visibly not working. At least explicitly call `wait` before `NLA_async` if that's what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I tried dispatching the blocks to new threads and get rid of the waiting altogether. This led to 100s of threads being created rendering the program unresponsive. Will be switching to a thread pool based approach now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I printed the thread id and apparently the threads are reused or something. `std::this_thread::get_id()` I have the feeling that not all threads are necessarily created. I am not sure where the problem is yet.c Could be the copy when returning from `NLA`? I will try to find out!

Comment: I think Useless is right. The second thread is created first and will then be assigned to the variable, waiting for the first one to finish. Hence, the second one will already run.

Comment: After further investigation I come to the same conclusion. Thanks for asking this question it made me dive deeper into futures and promises in c++ :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue of two threads running asynchronously is likely related to the fact that creating the future and assigning it to the member variable doesn't happen in one step.

First, it is created and the thread is started. Then, it is assigned to the member variable while waiting for the first thread to finish.

Thanks to Useless for pointing that out!